# apply() not working when checking column class in a data.frame

Tags: r, class, apply

I have a dataframe. I want to inspect the `class` of each column.

```
x1 = rep(1:4, times=5)
x2 = factor(rep(letters[1:4], times=5))
xdat = data.frame(x1, x2)

> class(xdat)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(xdat$x1)
[1] "integer"
> class(xdat$x2)
[1] "factor"
```

However, imagine that I have many columns and therefore need to use `apply()` to help me do the trick. But it's not working.

```
apply(xdat, 2, class)
         x1          x2 
"character" "character"
```

Why cannot I use `apply()` to see the data type of each column? or What I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use

```
sapply(xdat, class)
#     x1        x2 
# "integer"  "factor"
```

using `apply` would coerce the output to `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single 'class'.  If there are 'character' columns, the result would be a single 'character' class. To understand this check

```
 str(apply(xdat, 2, I))
 #chr [1:20, 1:2] "1" "2" "3" "4" "1" "2" "3" "4" "1" ...
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # ..$ : NULL
 # ..$ : chr [1:2] "x1" "x2"
```

Now, if we check

```
 str(lapply(xdat, I))
 #List of 2
 #$ x1:Class 'AsIs'  int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 #$ x2: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the coercion thing. Haven't used R for a while; such a rookie mistake.

Comment: @JasonV, Thanks, most of the `*apply` based solution works except the `apply` i.e. `rapply(xdat, class); vapply(xdat, class, character(1L))`

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of `rapply` actually!

Comment: The heart of this is that "using apply would coerce the output to matrix and matrix can hold only a single 'class'. "