# Create list of lists from tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to do something that seems very simple, but I cannot figure it out. I have a tibble like so:

```
> df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col_a, ~col_b,
  1,      "A",   
  2,      "B",   
  3,      "C",   
)
> df
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# col_a col_b
# <dbl> <chr>
#   1     A    
#   2     B    
#   3     C
```

and I want to turn it into a list that looks like this

```
> str(res_list)
# List of 3
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ col_a: num 1
# ..$ col_b: chr "A"
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ col_a: num 2
# ..$ col_b: chr "B"
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ col_a: num 3
# ..$ col_b: chr "C"
```

I tried a number of things using base `apply` and `dplyr::rowwise` but nothing worked quite right. In the docs for `purrr::pmap` I thought I found the answer:

```
f.   A function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic)...

If character vector, numeric vector, or list, it is converted to an extractor function. Character vectors index by name...
```

So I thought, great this should work: `pmap(df, c("col_a", "col_b"))` and that should extract those columns for each element (row) and return a list of the extracted lists. But when I run that I get:

```
 Error in pluck(x, "col_a", "col_b", .default = NULL) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I semi-understand this error, but I *think* I'm following the usage in the docs. Maybe this is just a bug in purrr?

Anyway, commentary on the potential purrr bug is welcome, but really I'm just trying to create this list. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the issue you had with `apply`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187425/apply-not-working-when-checking-column-class-in-a-data-frame, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392216/why-does-as-factor-return-a-character-when-used-inside-apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `group_split()` (or base `split()` if you prefer):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(row_number(), .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(as.list)
```

Where `str()` gives:

```
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: num 1
  ..$ col_b: chr "A"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: num 2
  ..$ col_b: chr "B"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: num 3
  ..$ col_b: chr "C"
```

Or:

```
lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)),
       as.list)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had not considered `group_split()` by row number. This feels very like SQL for some reason. The `lapply` option works too, but it names each element of the list with the row number, which might be fine but is a little less clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `asplit()`:

```r
type.convert(lapply(asplit(df, 1), as.list), as.is = TRUE)
```

or `by()`

```r
`attributes<-`(by(df, 1:nrow(df), as.list), NULL)
```

Both of `str()` give

```
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: int 1
  ..$ col_b: chr "A"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: int 2
  ..$ col_b: chr "B"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ col_a: int 3
  ..$ col_b: chr "C"
```

Comment: This looks good on the surface, but note the comment on another answer (although now I see that answer is deleted, so please don't delete this answer) that points out how `lapply` mysteriously converts everything to a character vector. This is especially bad if your real tibble is more complex than the one in the example.

Comment: @seth127 Fixed. please check.

Comment: Yes, those both work too. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
dflist <- df %>%
              pmap(~ list(...))
str(dflist)
#List of 3
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ col_a: num 1
#  ..$ col_b: chr "A"
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ col_a: num 2
#  ..$ col_b: chr "B"
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ col_a: num 3
#  ..$ col_b: chr "C"
```